# Collation sequence on datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

How to sort order query result in a collation sequence used in Germany?

For example: N, O, Ó, Ö, P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine doesn't directly support localized collations.

One way to handle the problem, assuming a single localization, is to precompute a 'canonical' form that will will collate correctly using the non-localized sort.

Comment: I create a orderProperty without accents and capitalized to make sort order correctly. Works fine. Thanks!